# Attempting scheduled auto Lead creation

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, compile-error

I am attempting to distribute Leads from a list on a weekly basis. I have this code which somebody was kind enough to help me with :

```
global class WeeklyPreOppProcessor {
{
    global void execute (SchedulableContext scx)
    {

        Group group = [Select Id, Name FROM Group 
                       WHERE Type = 'Queue' 
                       AND Name = 'Distributed_Queue'];

        List<Lead> lstLead = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId 
                              FROM Lead 
                              WHERE Distributed__c = false LIMIT 50];
        for(Lead leadObj:lstLead)
        {
            leadObj.Distributed__c = true;
            leadObj.OwnerId = group.Id;
        }
        update lstLead;
    }

}
```

But this is producing an error : "Global variable must be contained in a global class...". I don't understand this since I have the class labeled as global.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare variables as global. Earlier I have given this code. Just made small changes.

```
global class WeeklyPreOppProcessor implements Schedulable
{
    global Group grp;
    global List<Lead> lstLead;
    global void execute (SchedulableContext scx)
    {

        grp = [Select Id, Name FROM Group 
                       WHERE Type = 'Queue' 
                       AND Name = 'Distributed_Queue'];

        lstLead = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId 
                              FROM Lead 
                              WHERE Distributed__c = false LIMIT 50];
        for(Lead leadObj:lstLead)
        {
            leadObj.Distributed__c = true;
            leadObj.OwnerId = grp.Id;
        }
        update lstLead;
    }

}
```

Comment: I"m trying your code and am still getting a "global variable must be contained in a global class" error.

Comment: There was an extra { on line 2. I was then getting a "Identifier name is reserved: group at line 6 column 15" error. Not sure what that is. I haven't gotten to the test script yet.

Comment: Yha, that's what I did. And the group identifier apparently had to be changed to something else because it was a reserved name - so I changed it to group1 and it worked.

Comment: Declaring the variables is completely unnecessary, as is the `global` accessibility modifier (`public` should suffice).

Comment: Yes, thats true, actually his issue is Group variable name is also group, that's why the issue was

Comment: No, as explained in my answer the compile fail was induced by using an initializer block. The reserved identifier didn't even get a chance to screw things up, as the initializer took precedence.

Comment: I've got it saved and active but I can't find it in the list when I attempt to use the Schedule Apex button. Am I missing something else ?

Comment: I think you are missing something, as I can create this class and able to schedule at my DE

Comment: Ha - it just popped up. I swear I didn't do anything different, was even refreshing the screen out of desperation. Very weird. Thanks again Santanu.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra opening curly bracket (`{`). That's forcing everything inside of it to be considered an **[initializer block](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)** and really confusing the poor compiler.

```
global class MyClass {
    {
        // stateful initializer code
    }
}
```

Once you remove the extra curly bracket, you'll get a new compile fail:

> Identifier name is reserved: group

Once you rename that (to something like `distributedQueue`), your code will be good to go. Note also in your class declaration that you forgot to implement the `Schedulable` interface. Also note that you don't need to use `global` and should almost never use it unless you're working on package development. So your proper class should look like:

```
public class Demo implements Schedulable
{
    public void execute (SchedulableContext scx)
    {

        Group distributedQueue = [
            SELECT Name FROM Group 
            WHERE Type = 'Queue' 
            AND Name = 'Distributed_Queue'
        ];
        List<Lead> records = [
            SELECT Name, OwnerId FROM Lead
            WHERE Distributed__c = false LIMIT 50
        ];
        for(Lead record : records)
        {
            leadObj.distributed = true;
            leadObj.OwnerId = distributedQueue.Id;
        }
        update records;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been setting up scheduled jobs for this. It runs but it doesn't make the changes. I am using it on a custom object which I don't think should be a problem. I even took out the part of assigning the Owner in case that was a problem. It still won't make any changes. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Zoom_v Sounds like a separate question!

Comment: ok - I didn't know if it would have been considered wrong to start a new thread. Thanks.

Comment: @Zoom_v The reason this code failed to compile is very different than the reason the code doesn't update your records and requires different investigative/reproduction measures.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example

```
global class updateData implements Schedulable {   
global void execute (SchedulableContext SC) {       
    DataContact dContact = new DataContact();       
    dContact.UpdateContact();       
}
```

}

It looks like you are trying to execute the similar code (code mentioned above)inside the Dev Console. The Developer Console does not support creating global classes. If you are just trying to anonymously call UpdateContact, then you can simply type this into the Developer Console:

DataContact dc = new DataContact();
dc.updateData();

If you are trying to create a schedulable object to schedule calls to DataContact then you should create an Apex class with the code that you posted and then schedule it using the 'Schedule Apex' button on the Apex Classes page.

Comment: J - I am not using the Dev Console. I'm just trying to create that class in the Apex Class section. I would like to be able to just schedule that Santanu's class with the Schedule Apex button if I could just get it to save. But I'm getting that global variable error.